# Java Selenium, how to get linkText (anchor) from link WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a WebElement containing link found by url.  I can extract url by:

```
element.getAttribute("href");
```

But the question is: how to extract it's anchor, I'm trying like this:

```
webElement.getAttribute("linkText");
```

It gives me null value. I'm 100% sure this link has an anchor. Is there any way to get anchor ? It's more complicated, but example simplified code could look like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java");
        WebElement link  = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Bicycles"));

        System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href")); // shows http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/
        System.out.println(link.getAttribute("linkText")); // shows null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(link.getText());
```

Answer (score 5):

If getText() returns an empty String, try the innerHTML attribute:

```
String text = element.getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: Usually, the link text value goes together with unnecessary carriage return symbols and whitespaces. it's better to trim them all like this: 
`String text = element.getAttribute("innerHTML").replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "").trim();`

Answer (score 1):

By "Anchor" I think you mean the text of the link? If so, then you can use `.getText()` since an `<a>` is a block level element.

```
link.getText();
```

Comment: <a> or anchor tag a.k.a hyperlink is not block level element, it's inline element

Answer (score 1):

Here you can store your id text:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("Text")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```