# Taking text form anchor link and store it in the list

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The below code is giving me the complete innerHTML part, but I, want only the text inside that and store it in the list

The Code is

```
List<String> titles = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The out Put -

```
<a href="/nuxeo/portal/brand/ck/collection/403a5139-078f-47d2-b8e3-bc2215162f36/asset/0493a9f8-1f95-40cb-ba38-d4f188e0648d">1824 and 1834 test presentation</a>
```

Expected Output – any text falling inside the anchor tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Selenium, how to get linkText (anchor) from link WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796984/java-selenium-how-to-get-linktext-anchor-from-link-webelement)

Answer (score 1):

To get inner text (text that appears between opening and closing of any tag), use getText() method of WebElement, i.e.,

```
List<String> titles = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note - I'm not sure of or verified your Java syntax, just copy-pasted your code and replaced the method.